# How to validate for ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, joi, objectid

Using Joi schema validation, is it possible to validate against MongoDB ObjectID's?

Something like this could be great:

```
_id: Joi.ObjectId().required().error(errorParser),
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can do Joi.objectId().required()

Comment: @whoami-fakeFaceTrueSoul
it throws error : <field> must be a string

Comment: @AmirMeyari `String` inside `ObjectId()` i.e., `_id` should be a valid one (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#objectid)!! Print the value & check what's coming in!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')
Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi)
 
const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.objectId(),
  name: Joi.string().max(100),
  date: Joi.date()
})
```

checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid

Comment: Does this work with `Joi` (the "naked" version)? since the `@hapi/joi` was deprecated.

Answer (score 23):

I find that if I do

```js
Joi.object({
  id: Joi.string().hex().length(24)
})
```

it works without installing any external library or using RegEx

The `hex` makes sure the string contains only hexadecimal characters and the `length` makes sure that it is a string of exactly 24 characters

Answer (score 4):

This package works if you are using the new version of Joi.

```
const Joi = require('joi-oid')

const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.objectId(),
  name: Joi.string(),
  age: Joi.number().min(18),
})
```

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-oid

Comment: is this actually an entire NPM library wrapping a regex for ObjectIds?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you talking about but I mean people shouldn't download a entire package instead of using a simple regex.

Comment: No one has to download it. Codes are on github. Anyone can use it without the package. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a TypeScript version of the above library integrated with Express without installing anything:

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import { createValidator } from 'express-joi-validation';

export const JoiObjectId = (message = 'valid id') => Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/, message)

const validator = createValidator({
    passError: true,
});

const params = Joi.object({
    id: JoiObjectId().required(),
});

router.get<{ id: string }>(
    '/:id',
    validator.params(params),
    (req, res, next) => { 
       const { id } = req.params; // id has string type
       .... 
    }
);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A simple RegEx pattern instead of a whole additional library.

Answer (score 1):

I see many correct answers here, but I also want to express my opinion.
I am not against installing npm packages, but installing one package just to validate an object id is overkill. I know programmers are lazy but C'mooon :)

Here is my full code function that validates two object id properties, very simple:

```
function validateRental(rental) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    movieId: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/, 'object Id'),
    customerId: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/, 'object Id'),
  })

  const { error } = schema.validate(rental)

  return {
    valid: error == null,
    message: error ? error.details[0].message : null,
  }
}
```

This way, if any of the properties contain invalid id like this:

```
{
    "movieId": "123456",
    "customerId": "63edf556f383d108d54a68a0"
}
```

This will be the error message:

```
`"movieId" with value "123456" fails to match the object Id pattern`
```

Answer (score 0):

I share mine

```js
let id =
  Joi.string()
    .regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)
    .message('must be an oid')
```

Answer (score 0):

With `joi` naked package you can use this:

```
const ObjectId = joi.object({
   id: joi.binary().length(12),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a core function without any external package. I have used `Joi` and `mongoose` packages to achieve it.

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

const schema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().custom((value, helpers) => {
            const filtered = ObjectID.isValid(value)
            return !filtered ? helpers.error("any.invalid") : value;
        },
        "invalid objectId", ).required(),
    name: Joi.string(),
    age: Joi.number().min(18),
})
```