# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XXXXXXXXXX" (type string) at path "_id" for model "XXXX"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a beginner.

when i'm testing route with wrong (short) ID, for example instead of `"6261220286e8d5e7ee6f221e"` i'm putting `"6261220286e8d5e7ee6f221"`  node app crashes with this error:

[image: Screenshot of Node ERROR]

here is the route code:

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    //Validate with Joi
    const { error } = validateGenre(req.body);
    //If invalid, return 400 - Bad Request.
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    //Look up the genre and Update.
    const genre = await Genre.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { name: req.body.name }, { new: true })
    //If not exists, return 404.
    if (!genre) return res.status(404).send('The genre with the given ID was not found');
    //Return ubdated genre.
    res.send(genre);
});

function validateGenre(genre) {
    const schema = Joi.object({ name: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required() });
    return schema.validate(genre);
}
```

here also Genre schema:

```
const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50,
    }
});

const Genre = new mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);
```

My question is: How to handle this type of error, or how to validate requested ID length to return proper message to the client.

Sorry again, I'm really a beginner and thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658864/how-to-validate-for-objectid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `try catch` ??, in catch section you can do response with status 500 and an error message thrown by `Genre`

Comment: Yes I've done it with try catch but, that's not enough, i mean, error message like this: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "62619fc5b943844dcac" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Genre" doesn't look clear, however i can manually write custom error message but ... mmm maybe there is an other way to validate ID length and use that validator in other routes.